# Stream or Publish Real Time Data from Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

The end goal is to have a UI that allows real time monitoring or echo of values being inserted to a table in a sql database. This monitoring is not critical, so guaranteed delivery is a lower priority than the impact on the performance of the sql server. The table in question gets inserts of 2k to 5k rows per minute.

What mechanisms are there that would allow sql server to fire and forget to a queue or service bus with the least amount of impact to sql itself?

Comment: Service Broker? Can something other than sql server consume a service broker? 

A trigger? I hate the thought, but what about a trigger on the table to fire and forget to something? I was wondering about a queue, but I don't want a chance that a queue filling up or being unavailable causing issues with an insert trigger.

Answer (score 0):

There are some options with SQL CLR, if it's available, either using triggers or CLR SPs called from other SPs that are doing the INSERTs.

You could use Service Broker to send a message to another server, to distribute the load.

Since the monitoring isn't critical, if it's only needed once in a while, you could look at using a programmatic interface to same hooks used by SQL Profiler, or perhaps SQL Profiler itself.

If you system architecture is client-server, you could create "tasks" to do the logging / monitoring whenever the INSERT actions are called, and queue them to a background thread, where they could be processed at a lower priority, and even written to an entirely different database server, to avoid impacting performance.

Unfortunately, if you're on Azure, Service Broker and SQL Profiler aren't available.